# Как в С++ в регулярном выражении задать символ `“`?

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, c++17, std-regex

Требуется распарить CMake файл, где названия файлов исходного кода заключены в двойной апостроф. Тут я столкнулся с проблемой что я не могу задать `“` в самом регулярном выражении.

Код для примера:

```
    std::string str_1{"\
    \"main.cpp\"                                \
    \"CoreModules/app_constants.h\"             \ 
    \"CoreModules/bs_and_radio_settings.h\"     \ 
    \"CoreModules/bs_and_radio_settings.cpp\"   \
    \"CoreModules/command_manager.h\"           \
    \"CoreModules/command_manager.cpp\""};

    std::regex reg{"\\".+?\\""}; // Тут я хочу хочу написать выражение ".+?"
    std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(str_1.begin(), str_1.end(), reg);
    while (i != std::sregex_iterator()) {
        std::smatch m = *i;
        std::cout << m.str() << " - ";
        i++;
    }
    std::cout << endl;
```

Qt Creator 4.9.2; GCC 8.3.

Comment: `std::regex reg{"\".+?\""}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew помогло, спасибо большое.

Comment: Задайте символ в heх представлении `\x{YYYY}` (или другом представлении через код символа) с указанием кода именно вашей кавычки.

Comment: @nick_n_a Зачем такие сложности?

Comment: Мало ли что имеется ввиду под словом кавычка. Может имеется ввиду обратная кавычка. В вопросе - обратная, в примере прямая. Возможно нужно через `[]` перечислить все виды кавычек, т.к. юзеры программ бывают изобретательны. Я, делая валидацию, встречал 5 видов кавычек, и почти 10 видов апострофов с разными кодами.